# Change Property on a Range of ActiveX ComboBoxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a sheet with two columns of ActiveX ComboBoxes.  I want to be able to update the columns separately but haven't been able to figure out a clean way to do it.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
Sub UpdateNames()

Dim TotalCount As Integer
Dim VariableText As String

TotalCount = Worksheets("Variables").Range("C1")

VariableText = "Variables!$B$1:$B$" & TotalCount

ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox2").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox3").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox4").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
```

etc.

C1 just contains a number.  This method works, but really sucks.  What I'd like is one line of code instead of a bunch of lines for each combobox.  e.g.:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBoxX").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
```

This has to be super simple and I feel stupid for having to ask.  I read that an array would work, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.  I'd also like to be able to use this macro on another sheet named "Roster".  Would this code work?

```
Roster.Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = VariableText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = _ 
                                                                     VariableText
Next i
```

further to your comment:

if you want to change boxes from 1 to 3 only then modify `For i = 1 To 3`

Comment: Quick question.  Will that change every combobox on ActiveSheet?  How would I stop it at a specific number?  I have two columns of comboboxes and I only want to update one of them.